# OpenMP gathering data (join data?) after parallel for

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

What I am looking for is what is the best way to gather all the data from the parallel for loops into one variable. OpenMP seems to have a different routine then I am used to seeing as I started learning OpenMPI first which has scatter and gather routines.

Calculating PI (embarrassingly parallel routine)

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_STEPS 100
#define CHUNKSIZE 20

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double step, x, pi, sum=0.0;
    int i, chunk;

    chunk = CHUNKSIZE;
    step = 1.0/(double)NUM_STEPS;

    #pragma omp parallel shared(chunk) private(i,x,sum,step)
    {

        #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk)
            for(i = 0; i < NUM_STEPS; i++)
            {
                x = (i+0.5)*step;
                sum = sum + 4.0/(1.0+x*x);
                printf("Thread %d: i = %i sum = %f \n",tid,i,sum);
            }
        pi = step * sum;
    }
```

EDIT: It seems that I could use an array sum[*NUM_STEPS / CHUNKSIZE*] and sum the array into one value, or would it be better to use some sort of blocking routine to sum the product of each iteration

Comment: Would you post a working non omp version? I think I can help you to get omp to dance for you, but a compiling program would be nice.

Comment: I added the headers, the program will compile and run but what I really need is for the sums of each chunk to be added together after each iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets see, I am not quite sure what happens, because I havn't got deterministic behaviour on the finished application, but I have something looks like it resembles π. I removed the `#pragma omp parallel shared(chunk)` and changed the `#pragma omp for schedule(dynamic,chunk)` to `#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:sum)`.

**`#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:sum)`**

This requires some explanation, I removed the `schedule`s chunk just to make it all simpler (for me). The part that you are interested in is the `reduction(+:sum)` which is a normal reduce opeartion with the operator `+` and using the variable `sum`.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_STEPS 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double step, x, pi, sum=0.0;
    int i;

    step = 1.0/(double)NUM_STEPS;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:sum)
    for(i = 0; i < NUM_STEPS; i++)
    {
        x = (i+0.5)*step;
        sum +=4.0/(1.0+x*x);
        printf("Thread %%d: i = %i sum = %f \n",i,sum);
    }
    pi = step * sum;
    printf("pi=%lf\n", pi);
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Ty for answer you and Imre Kerr seemed to answer at the same time but you had commented on my question first so yours is accepted.

Comment: Why did you do schedule(dynamic)?  It looks to me like each thread should take the same time.  You should use schedule(static).

Comment: No reason in particular, it was not the important part in the question so I just let it be `dynamic`.

Answer (score 2):

Add this clause to your `#pragma omp parallel ...` statement:

```
reduction(+ : pi)
```

Then just do `pi += step * sum;` at the end of the parallel region. (Notice the plus!) OpenMP will then automagically sum up the partial sums for you.

Comment: Upvote Ty! Seems so simple now. reduction was at the end of the documentation for OpenMP!